# chrome fall into infinite loading after get WWW-Authenticate

Tags: c#, http, sockets

```cs
string serverResponse_header = $"HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\r\n";
string serverResponse_wwwAuthenticate = $"WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm=\"securityArea\", qop=\"auth\", nonce=\"{convertedNonce}\"\r\n\r\n";
clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serverResponse_header + serverResponse_wwwAuthenticate));
```

after get chrome's GETresponse, i send this digest www-authenticate message, but chrome fall into infinite loading, chrome's login popup show when server is close connection(same situation on edge browser too), i can do this by send that message and close connection, and get client's authenticate message, but I heard that can do on while connected,

can help me please

```cs
Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ipendpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5001);
Console.WriteLine($"server ipaddress : [{ipendpoint.Address}];[{ipendpoint.Port}]");
serverSocket.Bind(ipendpoint);
serverSocket.Listen(3);
Console.WriteLine($"waiting for client...");
while (true)
{
   Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
   Console.WriteLine($"new client : [{clientSocket.AddressFamily}]");
   string clientMessage = getMessage(clientSocket);

   RandomNumberGenerator nonceGenerator = 
   RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
   byte[] nonce = new byte[16];
   nonceGenerator.GetBytes(nonce);
   string convertedNonce = Convert.ToBase64String(nonce);
   Console.WriteLine($"generated nonce : [{nonce}], converted : [{convertedNonce}]");
   string serverResponse_header = $"HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\r\n";
   string serverResponse_wwwAuthenticate = $"WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm=\"securityArea\", qop=\"auth\", nonce=\"{convertedNonce}\"\r\n\r\n";
                
   clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serverResponse_header + serverResponse_wwwAuthenticate));
   Console.WriteLine($"message sended,\n{serverResponse_header + serverResponse_wwwAuthenticate}");
   clientMessage = getMessage(clientSocket);

   string[] clientresponse_lines = clientMessage.Split('\n');
   for (int i = 0; i < clientresponse_lines.Length; i++)
   {
     Console.WriteLine($"[{i}:] {clientresponse_lines[i]}");
   }
}
```

this is full code !!